# angularjs - How to select and delete multiple rows sqlite

Tags: angularjs, sqlite, cordova, ionic-framework

I have this app where I take picture and save the image URL into the sqlite .
i can add, delete and display all of them  , now i'm trying to select multiple (images)  from the db with the ids and delete the selected ones

```
$scope.selected = [];
    $scope.deleteMultiple = function(){
        var selectedImages = [];
    angular.forEach($scope.selected, function(isSelected, index) {
            if(isSelected)
            selectedImages.push($scope.images[$index])
            $scope.delete(selectedImages.id)
        })
    console.log(selectedImage)
        }


 $scope.add = function(path) {             
            if (imagesP != null) {          
                $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, "INSERT INTO imageTable (images) VALUES(?)", [path] );        
            }        
            alert("Inserted.");      
        },
        function(e) {        
            alert(e);      
        };

    $scope.delete = function(id) {                
            if (id != '') {          
                $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, "DELETE FROM imageTable WHERE id=?", [id]);        
            }        
            alert("Deleted.");        
            $scope.ShowAllData();      
        },
        function(e) {        
            alert(e);      
        };    

      
 $scope.getImgIDbyName = function(name) {

    console.log('[getImgIDbyName] - get image with name:  ' + name );
    var sql = "SELECT * FROM imageTable WHERE image = '" + name + "';";
    console.log(sql);
    $cordovaSQLite.execute(db,
        sql
    ).then(
        function(res) {
            if (res.rows.length > 0) {
                if (res.rows.length > 1) {
                    console.log('[getImgIDbyName] - OOPS more than 1 image returned!!!!  ' + name );
                } else {
                    $scope.delete (res.rows.item(0).id);
                }
            } else {
                console.log('[getImgIDbyName] - no image found with name:  ' + name );
            }
        },
        function(error) {
            alert("error occured: " + error.message);
        }
    );



}
```

HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="image in images " > <!-- container -->

 <div>

    <img ng-src="{{image.image}}" style="width: 70%; height: 80%;"  ng-class="{'selected-image': selected[$index]}" ng-click="selected[$index] = !selected[$index] />

 <div  ng-click="getImgIDbyName(image.image)">
    <div style="font-size:2rem;margin:0.5rem 0 1rem" > DELETE IMAGE (ID:{{image.id}}) </div>
 </div>
     </div>


</div>      

    </ion-scroll>
```

Comment: **Describe the problem.** "It doesn't work" is not a problem statement.

Comment: What  is "now i'm trying to select multiple rows", how?

Comment: @ItsikMauyhas multiple images URL , then delete the selected ones

Comment: @georgeawg i'm trying to select multiple rows ( images ) from the sqlite db then delete the selected ones

Comment: Read [How to debug small programs.](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code should do multiple delete as you are expecting:

```
$scope.selected = [];
    $scope.deleteMultiple = function(){
        var selectedImages = [];
        var selectIDs = $scope.selected.map(function(x) {return x +',';};
        console.log(selectedImages.selectIDs)
        $scope.delete(selectedImages.selectIDs)
        }

$scope.delete = function(ids) {                
            if (ids != '') {          
                $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, "DELETE FROM imageTable WHERE id IN (?)", [ids]);        
            }        
            alert("Deleted.");        
            $scope.ShowAllData();      
        },
```

This post describes the "IN" clause for sqllite. https://www.techonthenet.com/sqlite/in.php

Comment: Thanks , that's what i was looking for.
i will test it and come back to you

Comment: How to connect it to the dom and replace the old function ...  getImgIDbyName(image.image)

Comment: I'm working based on this example http://plnkr.co/edit/XxE2cYRvPBYKl37erTax?p=preview

Comment: Please mark this reply as the answer, if it solves your problem.

Comment: done , can u help me with implementing the function to the html , thanks

Comment: Please check http://plnkr.co/edit/JOMryvDh1Zv1FdP45R9m?p=preview.
Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks a lot , it works great , may I ask how did you learn JS that good , how and how long did it take you :D

Comment: hello man , I have an issue with cordova , if you can help me , i would appreciated it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42246489/cordova-delete-files-after-sqlite-delete-it